# How to set value of UISlider from a UITextField

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, uislider

I am using Xcode 4.3 and I want to be able to edit the value of a UISlider using a UITextField. How can I do this? I have a slider that displays its value in a text field, but can I also set the slider's value from a text field?

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Break down the problem. How do **YOU** think you can do this?

Comment: Slider.value = [[textfield text] intValue];

Comment: Thanks @NSPostWhenIdle, I tried this:
-(IBAction) setslider:(id)sender

{    
    threshA.value=[[setThreshA text]intValue];   
}
With threshA as my slider and setThreshA as the text field but setting the text field still has no effect on the slider except it sets to zero. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you linking this action to your sliders "value changed" outlet?

Comment: Yes @NSPostWhenIdle it is linked to the slider's value changed outlet.. Could another text field that is set to display its value be interfering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "textField" is the name of your text field, I would add a target to it in your viewDidLoad method:

```
[textField addTarget:self
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

And then handle the change like you said:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange {

    Slider.value = [[textfield.text] intValue];

}
```

Hope this helps.