# UISlider to adjust to match UITextField Value

Tags: ios, swift

I have a textfield on a form where the value changes based on the slider. I am trying update the functionality so that when the user enters a value in the text field the slider will move to the correct position. My UISlider will be a value between 0 and 3.

I have been trying to use this post to help me but, I have not been able to get it to work: [How to set value of UISlider from a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586948/how-to-set-value-of-uislider-from-a-uitextfield)

Cheers,

I want the user to be able to use the slider or keyboard to enter the rate discount - but if they enter a value I want the slider to move to the right spot. Using the code given the app crashes. I think it's because of conflicting code. I have been linking the sider as an outlet. Is this correct?

Comment: it sends me to the class AppDelegate. I checked for phantom outlets and don't see any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Are you failing because yoru link is an Objective C version? So here is the swift equivalent. First, add a listener on your textfield like this

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

Then in your text field text change function, set value for your slider

```
func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    if let stringValue = textField.text{
        if let intValue = Int(stringValue){
            slider.setValue(intValue, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, Here is my edit code for part 1 orgDiscount.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("textFieldDidChange:")), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged). This is saved under - view did load . The func changed to this: func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        if let stringValue = orgDiscount.text{
            if let intValue = Int(stringValue){
                slider.setValue(Float(Double(intValue)), animated: true)
            }
        }
        
    } .  Saved outside view did load. I created a slider outlet. called slider. Its cashing my app

Comment: @KevinProctor Ok. What error message are you getting, on which line?

Comment: It kicks me back to AppDelegate and gives an error - Thread 1: Singal SIGABRT. It stops on the first line of the class

Comment: @KevinProctor That is too broad, most of the error will show that line. Look into your console to see what is actually the error because my piece of code should not have anything that can cause your error

Comment: can you confirm that I have the two pieces of code in the right sections of the view controler?

Comment: @KevinProctor Sure. Can you post your code? Or a github URL? Or screen shot?